# Find a vector in matrix when order matters in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix say `m` as follows:

```
> m
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    4    1    5    2    3
[2,]    5    2    3    4    1
[3,]    3    4    1    5    2
[4,]    1    5    2    3    4
[5,]    2    3    4    1    5
[6,]    4    1    5    2    3
[7,]    5    2    3    4    1
[8,]    3    4    1    5    2
```

and a vector named `vec` as follows:

```
> vec
[1] 3 1
```

I'd like to find all rows in `m` containing `vec` in the same order. e.g. the result should be like (note that the first, fourth and sixth rows are not of interest):

```
> res
[2,]    5    2    3    4    1
[3,]    3    4    1    5    2
[5,]    2    3    4    1    5
[7,]    5    2    3    4    1
[8,]    3    4    1    5    2
```

Would you please tell me how can I do so in R? Thanks

Comment: Is `vec` always of length 2? Or should the solution be more general?

Comment: it's actually an example. The solution should work in general. thanks

Comment: How long is "vec"? Will "3" and "1" each exist only once in its row? You could check if the first "3" is before the first "1" in each row using `m[(max.col(m == 3, "first") - max.col(m == 1, "first")) < 0, ]`. Also, what is the "dim" of "m"?

Comment: @alexis_laz 
thanks. "vec" could be of any length but not more than the number of columns in "m". also, both "m" and "vec" are free of repetitions. You could imagine "m" as a set of all permutations of length n where we are interested to find any sub-permutation placed in "m" considering the fact that order mattersd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a general solution. We can create a regex pattern for `vec` then check it against the data combined into a set of strings for each row:

```
v2 <- paste(vec, collapse=".*?")
df.vec <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m))
m[grep(v2, df.vec),]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [2,]    5    2    3    4    1
# [3,]    3    4    1    5    2
# [5,]    2    3    4    1    5
# [7,]    5    2    3    4    1
# [8,]    3    4    1    5    2
```

Comment: I think the regex might need some modifications since it seems to not account for 2+ digit numbers - `grepl(paste(c(4, 5, 1, 2), collapse = ".*?"), paste(c(1, 4, 15, 10, 12), collapse = " "))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using `apply`:

```
> m[apply(m, 1, function(x) all(c(3,1) %in% x) & which(x == 3) < which(x == 1)),]
#  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#2  5  2  3  4  1
#3  3  4  1  5  2
#5  2  3  4  1  5
#7  5  2  3  4  1
#8  3  4  1  5  2
```

Here's a general solution to it for any vectors:

```
> vec <- c(3,4,1,5)
> m[apply(m, 1, function(x) all(vec %in% x) & all(diff(sapply(vec, function(y) which(x == y))) > 0)),]
#  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#3  3  4  1  5  2
#5  2  3  4  1  5
#8  3  4  1  5  2
```

I'd put it in a function for more convenient use:

```
f <- function(m, vec) m[apply(m, 1, function(x) all(vec %in% x) & all(diff(sapply(vec, function(y) which(x == y))) > 0)),]
f(m, c(3,1,5))
#  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#3  3  4  1  5  2
#5  2  3  4  1  5
#8  3  4  1  5  2
```

Comment: Nice. Could it be extended to `vec` of any length?

Comment: @Jimbou, that won't respect the order

Comment: @docendo discimus thanks but it works only for this example. We actually are looking for a general solution

Comment: @docendodiscimus I just came back to your solution after a while. A slightly better computation for `all(diff(sapply(vec, function(y) which(x == y))) > 0)` would be `!is.unsorted(sapply(vec, function(y) which(x == y)))`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another attempt.

Since (1) `m[i, ]` and `vec` are repetition free and, (2) `m` being permutations  so `ncol(m) << nrow(m)` you could test whether each following column matches a following element of `vec` than its previous column(s).

```
ff = function(mat, vec) 
{
    matched = array(match(mat, vec, 0L), dim(mat))

    ans = seq_len(nrow(mat))
    for(j in 2:ncol(mat)) {
        zeroj = ans[matched[ans, j] == 0L]
        matched[zeroj, j] = matched[zeroj, j - 1L]
        ans = ans[matched[ans, j] >= matched[ans, j - 1L]]
    }

    ans
}
ff(m, c(3, 1))
#[1] 2 3 5 7 8
```

And benchmarking on larger data using a *modified* version of akrun's (fastest of all) answer:

```
akrun = function(mat, vec)
    which(!apply(mat, 1L, function(x) is.unsorted(match(vec, x))))

set.seed(007); MAT = do.call(rbind, replicate(1e6, sample(15), simplify = FALSE)); VEC = sample(15, 8)

system.time({ ansff = ff(MAT, VEC) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.70    0.08    0.78 
system.time({ ansakrun = akrun(MAT, VEC) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.28    0.06    5.35 
all.equal(ansff, ansakrun)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice benchmarks.  Can you include other functions also?

Comment: @akrun : Thanks. I did not include pierre's because it didn't give valid results and docendo's is very similar to yours but instead of `nrow(m)` explicit looping it involves a `nrow(m) * length(vec)` one. Either way, I mostly added the benchmarks because I found it interesting an exercise - OP doesn't mention anything about efficiency; besides I had to justify that half-hour I spent somehow... :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
m1[apply(m1, 1, function(x) {n1 <- match(vec,x)
    n1[1] <n1[2]}),]
#      v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#[1,]  5  2  3  4  1
#[2,]  3  4  1  5  2
#[3,]  2  3  4  1  5
#[4,]  5  2  3  4  1
#[5,]  3  4  1  5  2
```

Or

```
m1[apply(m1, 1, function(x) all(diff(match(vec, x))>0)),]
```